# jQuery keypress submit only on enter

Tags: jquery, html

when a user presses enter(submits) a comment on my site it submits, as i want it to. but if the user wants to make a new line ex the user presses shift+enter to make a new line and NOT submit

how is that made ? 
this is my code:

```
$('#commentfield').keyup(function(e){
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 13: //enter
$('#commentform').submit();
    break;        
   }
});
```

should i just make a new case with: case 13+16: ??

Comment: either of the answers help you? both provide functional code which you could use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jishnuap/zYEMv/ this may help you.

Comment: @Flaashing Try this out, if this is what you need.

Comment: thank you it is exactly what i need :) 
but could you tell me what the getCaret function does ?

Answer (score 1):

**...or the simple solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/McH8q/

jQuery/Javascript (jQuery 1.7.1)

```
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) //if enter is pressed
        if (!event.shiftKey) $('#testForm').submit(); //and shift IS NOT held down, submit form
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="testForm">
  <textarea placeholder="Try Shift + Enter"></textarea>
</form>
```